# Exception handling in __init__ method

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, exception

I am a beginner and just working on a problem. I have to raise an exception if an object is passed with a string argument, but the output of this program is blank. Could anyone help?

```
class RadiusInputError(Exception):
    pass

class Circle:
    def __init__(self,radius):
        self.radius=radius
        if type(self.radius) == "<class 'str'>":
            raise RadiusInputError

try:
    a = Circle('Hello')
except RadiusInputError:
    print("'Hello' is not a number.")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really shouldn't check for types in that manner

The reason you code does not work is because:

```
>>> type(type(str))
<class 'type'>
>>> type(str)
<class 'type'>
```

As you can see the printed representation of `type(str)` looks like a string you could compare against but the expression `type(self.radius) == "<class 'str'>":` is comparing a `type` on the left hand side with a `str` on the right hand side which will never evaluate to true. The way to check if something is a particular type is to use `isinstance` as follows:

```
class RadiusInputError(Exception):
    pass

class Circle:
    def __init__(self,radius):
        self.radius = radius
        if isinstance(self.radius, str):
            raise RadiusInputError

try:
    a = Circle('Hello')
except RadiusInputError:
    print("'Hello' is not a number.")
```

This works as expected, the rest of your code is fine, just change the type check.

Answer (score 0):

```
class CustomError(Exception):
    pass

class Circle:
    def __init__(self,radius):
        self.radius=radius
        result = isinstance(self.radius, str)
        if result == True:
            raise CustomError

try:
    a = Circle('Hello')
except CustomError:
    print("'Hello' is not a number.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the datatype of your object been created and rather try to write in the below format:

```
class RadiusInputError(Exception):
    pass

class Circle:
    def __init__(self,radius):
        self.radius=radius
        try:
            if not isinstance(self.radius, int):
                    raise RadiusInputError
        except RadiusInputError:
            print("'hello' is not a number.")

a = Circle('hello')
```